# How to make sql query to group and sum results by date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, yii2

In yii2 app I have `Payment` model with fields `id` (primary key), `u_id` (integer, means id of person that made this payment from `User` model), `sum` (integer) and `date`. Example:

```
+--------------------------------+
| Payment                        |
+--------------------------------+
| id | u_id | sum  | date        |
+--------------------------------+
| 1  | 1    | 400  | 2015-11-25  |
| 2  | 1    | 200  | 2015-11-25  |
| 3  | 2    | 500  | 2015-11-25  |
| 4  | 2    | 300  | 2015-11-25  |
| 5  | 1    | 100  | 2015-11-20  |
+--------------------------------+
```

**Q:** I want to group results by date and summarize `sum` fields of all rows for each `u_id` for every day and also show `total` row. How to do that...? Maybe without `total` row? On yii2 **or clean mysql**. Example of results:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| Date       | User id | Money, $     |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2015-11-25 |         | 1400 (total) |
| 2015-11-25 | 1       | 600          |
| 2015-11-25 | 2       | 800          |
| 2015-11-20 |         | 100 (total)  |
| 2015-11-20 | 1       | 100          |
+-------------------------------------+
```

`Payment` model:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Payment::find();

    // do we need to group and sum here?

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

I guess `ListView` will be easer then `GridView`, because we will be able to make some calculations for each result. View:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>User id</th>
            <th>Money, $</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?= ListView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'itemView' => '_item_view',
        ]) ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`_item_view`:

```
<tr>
    <td><?= $model->date ?></td>
    <td><?= $model->u_id ?></td>
    <td><?= $model->sum ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Maybe `select sum(\`sum\`), \`date\` from table group by \`date\``?

Comment: I'm not sure you can create such a result with 1 query, having the day totals + the details per user in 1 result. Could you add the sql query you would normally use for this if possible?

Comment: @chris85 you don't have the details using that query see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7af96/1

Comment: Oh yea missed that OP wanted userid as well.

Comment: @sirjay, take a look at my answer! It returns exactly what you need. There is a sqlfiddle also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select dt "Date", usr "User Id", 
      case when usr is null 
           then concat(money, ' (total)')
           else money
           end as "Money, $"
  from (
     select dt, null as usr, sum(vsum) as money
       from mytable
      group by dt
     union
     select dt, u_id, sum(vsum) as money
       from mytable
      group by dt, u_id
   ) a
  order by dt desc, coalesce(usr,0)
```

See it here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48102/6

What you need in plain MySql would be possible with analytical functions but since MySql doesn't support it, you have to emulate it.

In my solution, I've made a query that sum the money only by date

```
select dt, null as usr, sum(vsum) as money
  from mytable
 group by dt
```

The `null as usr` column is needed so I can use the `UNION` operator with the second part. This query will get all dates and money summed.

Then the second part

```
select dt, u_id, sum(vsum) as money
  from mytable
 group by dt, u_id
```

Wich will get all dates by user summing the money.

The third part is to make it as subquery so I can order it with by date, user. Remember that the user of the first part is null, so I make it so every as null become `0` so it will be shown first.

Comment: I wanted to solve this myself, this is a very good solution and I would mark it as answer if I could! Great query!!! But it should be translated to yii also

Comment: Well, the OP said on his question **On yii2 or clean mysql** Why complicate on yii2 if a plain sql will do the job just fine! Right ?! :) @davejal

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SqlDataProvider this way

```
$count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payment group by `date`, u_id', )->queryScalar();

$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => 'SELECT u_id, sum(`sum`)  as `sum` , `date`   FROM payment group by `date`, u_id',

    'totalCount' => $count,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [
            'u_id',
            'sum',
            'date',
        ],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);

 return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is let mysql calculate the totals using `WITH ROLLUP`.

```
select dt, u_id, sum(vsum)
from   payment
group by dt, u_id with rollup;

+------------+------+-----------+
| dt         | u_id | sum(vsum) |
+------------+------+-----------+
| 2015-11-20 |    1 |       100 |
| 2015-11-20 | NULL |       100 |
| 2015-11-25 |    1 |       600 |
| 2015-11-25 |    2 |       800 |
| 2015-11-25 | NULL |      1400 |
| NULL       | NULL |      1500 |
+------------+------+-----------+
```

If you don't want the overall total, you can eliminate that as well.

```
select * from (
    select dt, u_id, sum(vsum)
    from   payment
    group by dt, u_id with rollup
) q where dt is not null;

+------------+------+-----------+
| dt         | u_id | sum(vsum) |
+------------+------+-----------+
| 2015-11-20 |    1 |       100 |
| 2015-11-20 | NULL |       100 |
| 2015-11-25 |    1 |       600 |
| 2015-11-25 |    2 |       800 |
| 2015-11-25 | NULL |      1400 |
+------------+------+-----------+
```